# Does Apple have an email address, or must one call or mail them?

Tags: applecare

Does Apple have a customer service email address? I have checked their site, and I can only find phone numbers and a mailing address.

Comment: If you publish any email address on a large website, unreal amounts of spam are sent to those addresses.  Do you want to get service if your query could easily get filtered or deleted? Don't feel bad about going to store.apple.com and using the chat feature to get a human to help point you to the best place for service. (no matter where you are in the world)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not listed anywhere on the site, support@apple.com is a valid email address - but it simply sends an automatic email back, and the address is not monitored.

You're better off with the many support options listed on their support site: http://www.apple.com/support/contact/